# How to get product attribute array for associated product in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

Here I get the associated product collection from a configurable product ($full_product). I wanna get the associated product attribute however all the methods I've tried didn't work. I wanna loop through the attribute array.

```
$associated_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$full_product);

foreach($_attributes as $_attribute) {
}
```

The following does not work:

```
$_attributes = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProductAttributes($associated_products);
$_attributes = $associated_products->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($associated_products);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below.......

```
 $Product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($congiProdID);
    $attributes = $Product->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getConfigurableAttributes($Product);
    if (count($attributes)) {
                foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute $attribute */
                    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($attribute->getData());
    echo "</pre>"
                }}

// for getting all assocated products
 $allProducts = $Product->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getUsedProducts(null, $Product);
            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {

            }
```

Comment: unfortunately, that's not what Im asking here. Im asking to get product attribute array for associated product, not the configurable product. ($_attributes) Thanks